# Accessing an outlet in Interface Builder in Document-Based Application

Tags: macruby

With MacRuby 0.12 and XCode 4.4.1 (Mountain Lion), I created a Document-Based Application.

In my document window nib, I have two objects:

- A `NSTextView` (in a `NSScrollView`), which has a custom class `MyView`
- A `NSTextField`

In my Ruby code, I have in `MyView`:

```
attr_accessor :field
```

I would like to bind this value to the `NSTextField` in Interface Builder. 
When I select `Bind to`, the choices are limited to:

- Shared User Defaults Controller
- File's Owner
- Application.

I choose the latter but then what should be the Model Key Path?

Furthermore, where is Application in my code? I don't see it anywhere in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this bug:

https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/issues/135